# Finding the unbiased estimator of variance

Tags: variance

The information that I've been given:

**After a chemical spillage at sea, a scientist measures the amount, x units, of the chemical in the water at 15 randomly chosen sites. The results are summarized in the form ∑x=18 and ∑x^2=28.94. 
Before the spillage occurred the mean level of the chemical in the water was 1.1. Test at the 5 % significance level the hypothesis that there has been an increase in the amount of the chemical in the water.**

To solve this question, I'll need to the value of the unbiased estimator of the variance which is: 0.524.

I'm unable to apply the appropriate formula and get it.

What I know: 
Unbiased estimator of variance: (n/n-1) * (sample variance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: The (raw, biased) sample variance of $n$ measurements $x_i$ can be obtained by the formula
$$\sigma^2=\left(\frac1n\sum x^2\right)-\left(\frac1n\sum x\right)^2$$

Comment: Thank you, got it!

Comment: Yep that's what I plan to do. Though my 5 minute limit to accept answers will finish in the next 50 seconds.